# Loop in R to read sequentially numbered filenames and output accordingly numbered files

Tags: r, loops

I'm sure this is very simple, but I'm new to doing my own programming in R and haven't quite gotten a hang of the syntax for looping.

I have code like this:

```
mydata1 <- read.table("ph001.txt", header=TRUE)
# ... series of formatting and merging steps
write.table(mydata4, "ph001_anno.txt", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, sep="\t")

png("manhattan_ph001.png"); manhattan(mydata4); dev.off()
png("qq_ph001.png"); qq(mydata4$P); dev.off()
```

The input file **ph001.txt** is output from a linear regression algorithm, and from that file, I need to output **ph001_anno.txt**, **manhattan_ph001.png**, and **qq_ph001.png**. The latter two are using the qqman package.

I have a folder that contains ph001 through ph138, and would like a loop function that reads these files individually and creates the corresponding output files for each file. As I said, I'm sure there is an easy way to do this as a loop function, but the part that's tripping me up is modifying the output filenames.

Comment: `list.files` accepts a pattern argument;  `for( i in vec ){ ...}` accepts a character vector; and you could then strip the portions of the results that you wanted to pass as the file names (with `substr` or `sub`) given to `write.table`. I'm pretty sure you will find all these step illustrated many times over if you did a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `stringr` package to do a lot of the string manipulation you want in order to generate your file names, like so:

```
f <- function(i) {
    num <- str_pad(i, 3, pad = "0")
    a <- str_c("ph", num, "_anno.txt")
    m <- str_c("manhattan_ph", num, ".png")
    q <- str_c("qq_ph", num, ".png")

    # Put code to do stuff with these file names here
}
sapply(1:138, f)
```

In the above block of code, for each number in `1:138` you create the name of three files. You can then use those file names in calls to `read.table` or `ggsave` or whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. I'll give it a try.